# Oracle TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE named zone vs offset

Tags: oracle, datetime, timezone, timestamp, dst

In oracle, is the named timezone always stored?

I have been testing this column within our system, and in some places the timestamp is shown as:

```
26-FEB-09 11.36.25.390713 AM +13:00
```

but other times it's:

```
26-FEB-09 11.36.25.390713 AM Pacific/Auckland
```

If the value is being stored as the former, does that mean the actual timezone is not being stored?

I worry because if a future date is stored with only an offset we might not be able to determine the actual time in the original timezone, because you can determine a offset from a timezone, but not vice versa.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that setting the TimeZone and format within ODP.NET when a connection is opened seems to solve this problem:

```
OracleGlobalization info = conn.GetSessionInfo();
info.TimeZone = "Pacific/Auckland";
info.TimeStampFormat = "DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM";
info.TimeStampTZFormat = "DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM TZR";
conn.SetSessionInfo(info);
```

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty easy to test

```
 create table foo ( tswtz TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);
    /

insert into foo values (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('21-FEB-2009 18:00:00 -5:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'));


insert into foo values (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('21-FEB-2009 18:00:00 EST', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZR'));
    select tswtz, extract(timezone_abbr from tswtz), extract(TIMEZONE_REGION from tswtz)
from foo;


TSWTZ         EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_ABBRFROMTSWTZ) EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGIONFROMTSWTZ)                                
------------- ------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
21-FEB-09 06.00.00.000000000 PM -05:00   UNK                          UNKNOWN                                                          
21-FEB-09 06.00.00.000000000 PM EST      EST                             EST                                                              

2 rows selected
```

It stores what you tell it. If you tell it an offset, that offset could be good for one or more timezones, so why would it just pick one?

Comment: OK, cool, that's what I've expected.
So say I have a "created" column which I want to have a default value of the current timestamp.
Currently in my DB a call to systimestamp returns a timestamp with an offset. How do I change this to use the named timezone?
Thanks

Comment: Whoa... Oracle returns what you tell it to return. Any default behaviour is a default. Never rely on the default, always be explicit. And I don't think systimestamp has that but select to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') || ' ' || SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual will.

Comment: select  extract(TIMEZONE_REGION from systimestamp) from dual results in UNKNOWN

Comment: select to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') || ' ' || SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual;

Results in:

20090226 13:34:05.481439 +13:00 +11:00

Why is the SESSIONTIMEZONE 11?
And also how do I make the TZR format return the named timezone.

Cheers

Comment: that's probably an NLS setting. I'll try to find it later