# OracleTimeStampTZ error

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I am trying to create a new OraceTimeStampTZ object and I get "ORA-1830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string" and can't see why. When I examine the string passed to "new", it looks OK:

```
OracleTimeStampTZ dtzTimeIn = new OracleTimeStampTZ(sDTZ);
```

sDTZ = "15-APR-13 09.03.47.000000 AM US/EASTERN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi it seems like your time and year are incorrect based on the documentation from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleTimeStampTZStructure.htm).

Can you try if the following works:

```
OracleGlobalization info = conn.GetClientInfo();
info.TimeZone = "US/Easstern";
info.TimeStampFormat = "DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM";
info.TimeStampTZFormat = "DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM TZR";
conn.SetSessionInfo(info);

OracleTimeStampTZ dtzTimeIn = new OracleTimeStampTZ("15-APR-2013 09:03:47.000 AM US/Eastern");
```

I edited my previous answer to incorporate a code block provided in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588286/oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-named-zone-vs-offset) similar to this.

Comment: But the value in database is stored as "15-APR-13 10.03.54.000000000 AM US/EASTERN". Some are stored as "20-FEB-13 03.29.43.000000000 PM -05:00"

Comment: I updated my answer calling the OracleGlobalization first prior to using the time zone conversion. let me know if this works for you

Comment: I will give this a try but I am storing data using user's local time zone so I cannot rely on server's session info. I grab user's local time zone on client side, store it in a session variable and use it to insert any date/time data into database. I need to be able to display this data as EST, EDT, PST, etc.

Comment: I updated my code to use the client info so basically now it uses the client data. let me know if it works.