# MySQL ISO 8601 Date with Timezone offset instead of Z value

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, offset, iso8601

I need to SELECT a ISO 8601 Date.

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')
```

This produces something like

```
2013-11-13T15:47:530Z
```

But I need it with the offset instead of Z value:

```
2013-11-13T15:47:53+02:00
```

How can I do this with plain MySQL ?

Comment: How do you know which offset you want to specify?

Comment: You mean the timezone does not get saved in a mysql datetime object?
I want the offset of the datetime..

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware... (Note that an offset isn't the same as a time zone really, either.)

Comment: My DateTime's are in GMT+1 or GMT+2 during daylightsaving. I have orders with a datetime and I need to export them to the client with the offset e.g. +02:00.

Comment: Do you only actually care about the *instant*? If so, I'd suggest storing *everything* in UTC, and ideally setting the time zone of the database to UTC for good measure. Then do any other handling outside the database.

Comment: The times are saved in CET.. maybe the offset should just be +00:00 then ??

Comment: No, because CET *isn't* at offset 0. As I say, I think you should store them in UTC for simplicity. But I think you should do more research about what MySQL types represent - and also what your client can support. (We don't know what you're using to talk to MySQL...)

Comment: MySQL does not have a `datetimeoffset` type, but you could store two columns - a [`datetime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) for the main part and a [`time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html) type for the offset.  But like Jon said, it's probably easier just to convert to UTC and store a single `datetime` value.  Unless you have a specific need to persist the offset, it's not usually required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the timezone as an extra column in DB. I do not know any DB that stores datetime **with** timezone/offset.

Or store the date as string in ISO 8601 format with offset..

**Edit:** I stand somewhat corrected, with some **newer** databases it is possible!

- [Postgresql Date/Time Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html), which indeed may include timezone.

  - Datatype: "timestamp [ (p) ] with time zone" only for **input and output**, it is stored in UTC.
  - Datatype: "time with time zone", only time, stores timezone offset. **Since version 8.**
- [ORACLE Datetime Datatypes and Time Zone Support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081).

  - Datatype: "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE", stores timezone offset. **Since version 9i.**
  - Datatype: "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE", stores timezone offset or timezone name. **Since version 10g.**
  - See also [Oracle TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE named zone vs offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588286/oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-named-zone-vs-offset).
- [MicroSoft SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/03/18/using-time-zone-data-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

  - Datatype: "datetimeoffset", stores timezone offset.
- [Sybase](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/timestamp-with-timezone.html)

  - Datatype: "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE", stores timezone offset.
  - Support for TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE is optional SQL language feature F411 of the SQL/2008 standard.
- Seems to actually be somewhat standard [SQL99](http://sqlbible.uw.hu/sqlbible0023.html).
- Not for [Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-types.html). Version 5.6.
- Nor for [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). Version 3.

I do find consolation in the fact that the correction came from myself ;-)

Answer (score 2):

his snippet should work for iso 8601 without milis, zulu time is also not supported:

```
select IF(
LENGTH(value) < 23,
STR_TO_DATE(value,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'),
CASE SUBSTRING(value from 20 for 1)
WHEN '+' THEN
DATE_ADD(
STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(value from 1 for 19),'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'),
INTERVAL SUBSTRING(value from 21 for 2) HOUR)
WHEN '-' THEN
DATE_SUB(
STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(value from 1 for 19),'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ'),
INTERVAL SUBSTRING(value from 21 for 2) HOUR
)
END
)
from THE_NAMESPACE.THE_TABLE.THE_COLUMN as value;
```