# Query on a time zone converted date produce the wrong result

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

The data is store as PST but is entered in Asia/Dhaka, when I try to query on the Date Approved from 12/1/13 to 12/13/13 I'm getting some record from 12/14/13. The records was approved in Asia on 12/14/2013  6:27:45 AM and is stored on the DB as PST 12/13/2013  4:27:45 PM. When I query I'm suppossed to query on 'Asia/Dhaka' time. This is the conversion that I'm using:

```sql
FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE(dateapproved, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP),
        'America/Los_Angeles') AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Dhaka'
between TO_DATE('12/01/2013 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    and TO_DATE('12/13/2013 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

What do I need to do to get only the records that were approved on the specify date range as 'Asia/Dhaka' Time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use datatype [TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112227/3138898) in the table, and functions [DBTIMEZONE() or FROM_TZ()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006333) to convert.