# Oracle example value for TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi how will be example value for the column with datatype of `TIMESTAMP`?

Need some insert operation for it. `createdTime` is datatype of `TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE`

```
INSERT INTO table1 values(<id>, <firstName>, <createdTime>);
```

When I try like the following

```
INSERT INTO table1 values(1, "John", TIMESTAMP '06-APR-14 06.00.42.000000000 PM ASIA/SINGAPORE');
```

gives the SQL error;

```
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588286/oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-named-zone-vs-offset

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a [timestamp literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) you have to use a specific format:

```
INSERT INTO table1 values(1, 'John',
  TIMESTAMP '2014-04-06 18:00:42.0 ASIA/SINGAPORE');
```

You can be more flexible with a [`to_timestamp_tz` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions214.htm) call:

```
INSERT INTO table1 values(2, 'John',
  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('06-APR-14 06.00.42 PM ASIA/SINGAPORE', 
    'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS AM TZR'));
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f58c/2).

I've omitted the [`FF` format element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) since you don't want fractional seconds.

I've also changed the double quotes around `John` to single quotes, to stop it being interpreted as an identifier.